# Apportable: is using windows azure mobile services possible?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, apportable

I am trying to build my ios application for android. Is there any chance to use windows azure mobile services framework in native objective-c code? Or should I use java and call my azure mobile services table items from it ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Now I am trying to use azure mobile services android sdk + bridge kit's futures in my app (in objective-c) . If I run them all correctly I will share the files with a simple tutorial to connect azure mobile services in apportable android app.

Answer (score 1):

If there's an Android version of azure, you could use BridgeKit to bridge the android library to objective c APIs.

http://docs.apportable.com/using-java

Answer (score 0):

There are native Azure Mobile Services SDKs for all major mobile platforms (iOS / Objective-C, Android / Java, Windows Phone, etc).  There are excellent tutorials available on the Azure website:

- iOS: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started/
- Android: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started/

If you are looking for cross-platform development you could leverage Xamarin (C#), Sencha or PhoneGap which all have samples at the above site as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already build an app with azure iOS sdk, through apportable I am trying to make it work on android devices. I don't know java like objective-c thats why I don't want to rewrite the app for android in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve multiple platforms a better approach would be to create a service layer which works against your Mobile Service (f.e. build with ASP.NET Web API). This service layer would be called from your clients. The big advantage is that you don't have to write code multiple times and changes can be done at a central point. If you concentrate on RESTful services nearly every platform can call it.

Currently that seems to be a lot of overhead with an already finished iOS implementation, but imagine the situation when you want to support other platforms, such as Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8. At this point you have the same problems again.